# GWT: Replace AbstractPlaceHistoryMapper with a custom mapper using deferred binding

Tags: gwt, history, gwt-history

Looks like the class that is  generated for PlaceHistoryMapper   is hard-coded to use AbstractPlaceHistoryMapper as the super class.

So, I am trying to work around this by trying to replace this AbstractPlaceHistoryMapper  with a custom mapper of mine using deferred binding . I am using the following rule in my *.gwt.xml:

```
<replace-with class="com.google.gwt.place.impl.AbstractPlaceHistoryMapper">
   <when-type-is class="com.test.sampleapp.CustomPlaceHistoryMapper" />
</replace-with>
```

But for some reason the replace does not seem to be happening.  CustomPlaceHistoryMapper is not getting kicked in and the generated class  still uses AbstractPlaceHistoryMapper.

Any thoughts/pointers as to what might be resulting this behavior are much appreciated.

Note: I have also posted this on the GWT group but haven't received an answer so far.

Comment: I think Hilbrand's answer is correct. GWT.create(X) means that only  'X' goes through "deferred binding". If the generated class of 'X' extends any class  they (the extended class) will not be put through the process of "deferred binding.

Comment: Currently(GWT 2.2), if you use out-of-the-box Place-related classes(things like AbstractPlaceHistoryMapper etc) that GWT provides,  history tokens can only be of the form prefix:token, for eg.,  #mail:inbox. You can't have #mail/inbox or even just #mail. Clearly, this needs to be enhanced. Currently there is a issue open with the GWT team at http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5899 that would take care of this . Please star it , if you are interested in seeing this functionality implemented in the future releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the deferred binding work a class must be created with `GWT.create()`. However,  `AbstractPlaceHistoryMapper` is only used as an extended class. So it will never be created via GWT.create, but always by instantiation the subclass. And therefor deferred binding won't work in this case. If you want a complete different implementation you have to implement a custom `PlaceHistoryMapper`, and manage the known tokens yourself. This also means you can't use the History annotations either.

As a side note the classnames in your rule should be swapped. But for the end result this doesn't matter, since it won't work in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely possible to have custom history tokens (eg. `#mail` or `#mail/bla` instead of only `#mail:inbox`) using the out-of-the-box Place-related classes that GWT (2.0) provides.

Instead of replacing `AbstractPlaceHistoryMapper` you could instantiate the default `PlaceHistoryMapper` passing in it's constructor your implementation of `PlaceHistoryMapper<T>` or `PlaceHistoryMapperWithFactory<T>`.

eg.:

```
final PlaceHistoryHandler placeHistoryHandler = new PlaceHistoryHandler(new CustomHistoryMapper());
```

You will be able then to map tokens as you wish.

I personally recommend you to use an unique `PlaceTokenizer` in you mapper custom implementation so that I dont have to have an inner *PlaceTokenizer* class in each of your *Places*.

Hope that helps. Feel free to ask any doubts.